# Drop consecutive rows if condition is met in pandas df

Tags: pandas, conditional-statements, drop, col, consecutive-months

I have a data set in which a certain rows are getting repeated and i need to drop them

for example:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| john | 1 |
| next | nan |
| nan | nan |
| 123 | nan |
| smith | 2 |
| Pete | 3 |
| next | nan |
| nan | nan |
| 123 | nan |
| Angie | 2 |
| tom | 3 |

so every time 'Next' comes in 'column A', 3 rows including the row that contains 'next' needs to be deleted.

how can i solve this.

Comment: Welcome. Please add to your post what have you tried and what is causing a difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't want to just [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) on `Column B`, you could use a [`rolling.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.window.rolling.Rolling.max.html) on `Column A` to get `N` rows after the `next`:

```
N = 3
out = df[df['Column A'].eq('next').rolling(N, min_periods=1).max().eq(0)]
```

Output:

```
   Column A  Column B
0      john       1.0
4     smith       2.0
5      Pete       3.0
9     Angie       2.0
10      tom       3.0
```

Intermediates:

```
   Column A  Column B  eq('next')  rolling_max  eq(0)
0      john       1.0       False          0.0   True
1      next       NaN        True          1.0  False
2       NaN       NaN       False          1.0  False
3       123       NaN       False          1.0  False
4     smith       2.0       False          0.0   True
5      Pete       3.0       False          0.0   True
6      next       NaN        True          1.0  False
7       NaN       NaN       False          1.0  False
8       123       NaN       False          1.0  False
9     Angie       2.0       False          0.0   True
10      tom       3.0       False          0.0   True
```